# How to modify a string of symbols based on the positions of $1$'s in a list of Booleans?

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation, boolean-computation

Given a list of Booleans:

```
exampleInput = {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0};
```

and given the string:

```
string = "\\xa , \\xb , \\xc , \\xd , \\xe , \\xf , \\xg , \\xh";
```

The challenge is to replace the lower case letters $\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\}$ with capital letters $\{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H\}$ at the positions where $1$'s occur in the list of Booleans.

```
exampleOutput = "\\xA , \\xB , \\xc , \\xD , \\xe , \\xf , \\xG , \\xh"
```

### Challenge/Question:

come up with an elegant or surprising way to do this.

---

all code for convenience:

```
exampleInput = {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0};
string = "\\xa , \\xb , \\xc , \\xd , \\xe , \\xf , \\xg , \\xh";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** A few additional alternatives:

Make list of functions out of `exampleInput`:

```
foo = exampleInput /. {0 -> Identity, 1 -> ToUpperCase};
```

You can use `foo` with `StringReplace` or with `StringReplacePart` in several ways:

```
StringReplace[string, "x" ~~ a_ :> "x"<> Last[foo = RotateLeft[foo]][a]]
```

or (using @J.M.'s regular expression pattern):

```
StringReplace[string, 
  RegularExpression["(?![x])[a-z]"] :> Last[foo = RotateLeft[foo]]["$0"]]
```

or

```
Block[{i = 1}, StringReplace[string, "x" ~~ a_ :> "x"<> foo[[i++]][a]]]
```

or

```
pos = 1 + StringPosition[string, "x"];

StringReplacePart[string, Construct @@@ Thread[{foo, StringTake[string, pos]}], pos]
```

or

```
StringReplacePart[string, MapThread[Compose, {foo, StringTake[string, pos]}], pos]
```

**Original answer:**

```
StringRiffle[MapAt[StringReplace["x" ~~ a_ :> "x" <> ToUpperCase[a]], 
  StringSplit[string, ","], Position[exampleInput, 1]], ","]
```

> `"\\xA , \\xB , \\xc , \\xD , \\xe , \\xf , \\xG , \\xh"`

Alternatively,

```
spos = 1 + Pick[StringPosition[string, "x"], exampleInput, 1];

StringReplacePart[string, ToUpperCase[StringTake[string, spos]], spos]
```

> `"\\xA , \\xB , \\xc , \\xD , \\xe , \\xf , \\xG , \\xh"`

and

```
ClearAll[stringMapAt]
stringMapAt = StringJoin@MapAt[#, Characters@#2, #3] &;

stringMapAt[ToUpperCase, string, spos[[All, {1}]]]
```

> `"\\xA , \\xB , \\xc , \\xD , \\xe , \\xf , \\xG , \\xh"`

Answer (score 4):

A variation of the [first answer in kglr's post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/213441/29734) that doesn't deconstruct and reconstruct the list:

```
Module[{i = 1}, 
  StringReplace[
    string, "x" ~~ a_ :> "x" <> If[exampleInput[[i++]] == 1, ToUpperCase@a, a]
   ]
 ]
```

> `"\\xA , \\xB , \\xc , \\xD , \\xe , \\xf , \\xG , \\xh"`

Slightly more verbose but not requiring checking with the `If` statement:

```
Module[{i = 1}, 
  StringReplace[string, 
    "x" ~~ z_ :>  "x" <> FromCharacterCode[First@ToCharacterCode[z] - 32 exampleInput[[i++]]]
   ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to use a regex with "negative lookahead" in conjunction with `Pick[]`:

```
With[{pos = Pick[StringPosition[string, RegularExpression["((?![x])[a-z])"]], 
                 exampleInput, 1]},
     StringReplacePart[string, ToUpperCase[StringTake[string, pos]], pos]]
   "\\xA , \\xB , \\xc , \\xD , \\xe , \\xf , \\xG , \\xh"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
exampleInput = {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0};
string = "\\xa , \\xb , \\xc , \\xd , \\xe , \\xf , \\xg , \\xh";
```

Since this question seems more along the lines of [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) (which I'm all in favor of), I won't put generality as much of a priority.

### Replacement

```
With[
  {lets = Pick[Alphabet[][[;; Length@exampleInput]], exampleInput, 1](*{a,b,...,h}*)}, 
  StringReplace[string, char : Alternatives @@ lets :> ToUpperCase@char]
]
```

> ```
> "\\xA , \\xB , \\xc , \\xD , \\xe , \\xf , \\xG , \\xh"
> ```

### Brute force

```
With[
  {lets = Pick[Alphabet[][[;; Length@exampleInput]], exampleInput, 1]}, 
  If[MemberQ[lets, #], ToUpperCase@#, #] & /@ Characters@string // StringJoin
]
```

> ```
> "\\xA , \\xB , \\xc , \\xD , \\xe , \\xf , \\xG , \\xh"
> ```

### Pattern Exploitation

And if we want to use the symmetry/pattern that each a, b, etc are separated by 6 characters (starting at the third character of the string).

```
StringJoin@MapAt[
  ToUpperCase, 
  Characters@string,
  Thread@{Pick[Range[3, StringLength@string, 6], exampleInput, 1]}
]
```

> ```
> "\\xA , \\xB , \\xc , \\xD , \\xe , \\xf , \\xG , \\xh"
> ```

### Pattern exploitation, indicator functions, and generalized inner products

First we notice that the indexing letters (a, ..., h), denoted by `let`, all have 5 characters between them.

Then we pad the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) `exampleInput` (in the sense of which letters, out of all the letters, are to be capitalized) to be the same length as the string

```
indic = (exampleInput /. x : (0 | 1) :> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x} // Flatten)[[4 ;;]]
```

stripping off unnecessary leading zeros.  This gives a list of ones where the letters-to-be-capitalized are, and zeros elsewhere.

Then, being inspired from @kglr's `foo`

```
funcs = indic /. {0 -> Identity, 1 -> ToUpperCase}
```

Then we take the generalized inner product between `funcs` and the character list

```
Inner[#1@#2 & (*or Construct in version >= 11.3*), funcs, Characters@string, StringJoin]
```

> ```
> "\\xA , \\xB , \\xc , \\xD , \\xe , \\xf , \\xG , \\xh"
> ```

Or all together

```
With[
  {indic = (exampleInput /. x : (0 | 1) :> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x} // Flatten)[[4 ;;]]},
  Inner[#1@#2 &, indic /. {0 -> Identity, 1 -> ToUpperCase}, Characters@string, StringJoin]
]
```